# link between model cake php

Tags: cakephp

I try to use CakePhp but i don't find the solution. Here is my problem :

I have 2 models ant i try to link it. 
The First is Player (which mysql table is players)

The second is Toto (which mysql table is totos)
I have a field un players called toto_id

And in my model Player i wrote :

```
<?php
class Player extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );

    public $hasOne = 'Toto';
}
```

And in my controller PlayersController

```
class PlayersController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
    public $components = array('Session');

    public function index() {
        $params = array(
            'order' =>  array("Player.firstname")
        );
        $a = $this->Player->find('all', $params);
        print_r($a);
        $this->set('liste', $a);
    }
}
```

And my print_r displays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Player] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => DESMAISON
                    [firstname] => Christophe
                    [is_intern] => 1
                    [score] => 663
                    [created] => 2014-01-05
                    [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [toto_id] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Player] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => CHARLERY
                    [firstname] => DaphnÃ©
                    [is_intern] => 1
                    [score] => 572
                    [created] => 2014-01-04
                    [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [toto_id] => 0
                )

        )
```

I don't understand why in my array i haven't a reference to Toto. Someone can help me ?

Thank you for your help

Ps : i use cakephp 2.4.4 PHP 5.4.7

Comment: My appModel is empty like this :

App::uses('Model', 'Model');

class AppModel extends Model {
}

Why do you mean about recursivity ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is BelongsTo Association .

Instead of HasOne association try to use BelongsTo,

class Invoice extends AppModel {

```
public $belongsTo  = array(
    'Toto' => array(
        'className'    => 'Toto',
        'foreignKey'   => 'toto_id'
    ),
);
```

if you want to retrieve data from database you have to set your recursivity and there is two ways first one :

```
$players = $this->Player->find('all',array('recursive'=>2));
// or
$this->Player->recursive = 2;
$player = $this->Player->find('all');
```

Comment: i did it but it doesn't work. But i tried to rename the model classname of playermodel as playerazazaza and there is no error ...
How to be sure that the model is called ?

Comment: i wrote a die('aaa') in my Player model at the top of the file and i don't see the 'aaa' ... 
Why my model isn't called ?

Comment: define a simple method on your model test(); with a die() message , then try to call it on your controller , make sure u load the model properly with $this->loadModel('Player'); or the public $uses = array('Player'); or even with classregistry loader $this->Player = ClassRegistry::init('Player');

Comment: First of all thk u for the help. 

I've just realized that my model didn't called because of the wrong name. There was suffix by Model but in the "new version" it's not necessary !
My wrong name of model was PlayerModel.php and the good is Player.php

Have a nice week-end ;)

Comment: Lol , Congratz then ... you should read about the Cakephp conventions to avoid those problems

Comment: I red it by i began the project the last year and i update cake version and my model doesn't work ... but no message. The parent class was called ... 
Thank U :)